# Best practice for indicating prop is used in useEffect or similar

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Often when writing a component in React+Typescript, I want to trigger a useEffect hook on one of the props. For example, consider a button that executes a different function for each consecutive mouse click:

```
export function ActionButton({clickActions}: {clickActions: (() => void)[]}) {

  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (clickActions.length > 0 && clickActions[clicked % clickActions.length]) {
      clickActions[clicked % clickActions.length]();
    }
  }, [clicked, clickActions])

  return <button onClick={() => setClicked(clicked => clicked + 1)}/>
}
```

In this case, clients of this component, need to be aware that they somehow need to prevent `clickActions` from being a different instance on every render. For example, it could simply be a constant, or be memoized by using `useMemo`.

Is there a best practice for making my clients aware of this? Are there ways to trigger compile time errors when this rule is violated?

NOTE: I realize this particular case can be solved without using `useEffect`, but it's just a simple example to illustrate the pattern. I'm not interested in solving this particular problem, but in how to solve the general problem.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing you can do by way of TypeScript trickery to enforce that `clickActions` can't change every time the parent renders.

However, you can simply remove `clickActions` from `useEffect`’s dependency list. You have to be careful, in general, when doing this, but in this case, it's safe, because the callback you’re passing to `useEffect` *synchronously* executes an action when `clicked` changes, which means the callback will have a reference to the most *recent* `clickActions` when it needs it.

This is analogous to the [`sample`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/sample) operator in RxJS; i.e. `clickActions` is sampled by `clicked`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (clickActions.length > 0 && clickActions[clicked % clickActions.length]) {
    clickActions[clicked]();
  }
}, [clicked])
```

Please also note that even when the parent uses `useMemo`, it's not guaranteed that it won’t recreate `clickActions` at a time of React’s choosing:

> **You may rely on `useMemo` as a performance optimization, not as a semantic guarantee.** In the future, React may choose to “forget” some previously memoized values and recalculate them on next render, e.g. to free memory for offscreen components. Write your code so that it still works without `useMemo` — and then add it to optimize performance.

(see [useMemo docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo))

It's safe to assume `useCallback` comes with a similar caveat, although it's not specifically mentioned in the docs.

Comment: Thanks for that reference to the `useMemo` docs. That's interesting, but also very weird, because it seems to contradict with the docs for `useCallback`: "useCallback will return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed. This is useful when passing callbacks to optimized child components that rely on reference equality to prevent unnecessary renders (e.g. shouldComponentUpdate).

useCallback(fn, deps) is equivalent to useMemo(() => fn, deps)." (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)

Comment: So does this mean the same caveat is true for `useCallback`?

Comment: @wvdz you’re right. There’s a contradiction in the docs and it needs clarification. I wouldn’t look to the React source for clarification, because the current implementation of `useMemo` provides a semantic guarantee that we’re warned not to rely on.

Comment: Haha I have a lot of cleanup to do in my code if that's true

Answer (score 1):

generally if you have a function that is being passed around its important (especially if its 'created' within a function) to use `useCallback` when creating it. This ensures that the "props don't change" and thus preventing a rerender.

```js
parentFunction = useCallback(()=>{
  if (specialVar==='dance'){
    return () => {
      console.log('dance')
    }
  }
  else {
    return () => {
      console.log('do the boogy')
    }
  }
}, [specialVar])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think this answers the question. I'm aware of useCallback and its more general sibling useMemo. The question is: how do I let my clients know they should use it?